# Calling a function in another function to reduce repeated code

Tags: javascript, function, this, mousehover

I have two functions one thats triggered on a mouseenter event and the other on mouseleave. Both of these functions are repeated three times. 

On mouseenter the classlist "active" is addded 5x and the text content is changed.
On mouseleave the classlist active is removed 5x and the text content is set to an empty string, and the original image is displayed again. 

When the mouseenter event listener is triggered, Depending on which image is being hovered (3 images). 
the text content property that gets added various between the three "Photosnap" "Dine" "Nike".

 As-well as the background color that gets triggered various between "red" "blue" "pink".


[Hover state shown as red left image and normal state shown as right image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C80jk.jpg)

-The image shown here is one of three. It is displayed with a red background and the text content of "photosnap".

-The other with a blue background and the text content of "Dine".

-The third and final with a pink background and the text content of "Nike".

I hope this paints a clear picture i am having a hard time making this a code snippet.

I am trying to refactor this javascript so its not so repetitive. I'm new to javascript and having a hard time getting this to work as something other than what i currently have. I'm not clear on how to make a function that i can call inside of other functions to cut down on the repeated code. Or possibly use the "this" keyword ?

Javascript--

```
// //Photosnap Project #1 ---------------------------------------------------------

// Content in project on hover 
let projectTitle = document.querySelector('.projectTitlePhotosnap');
let projectLine = document.querySelector('.hoverLinePhotosnap');
// View live View code text wrapper
let projectRowWrap = document.querySelector('.flexWrapperRowPhotosnap');

// Background color + image
let photosnapBackground = document.querySelector('.photosnapBackground');
let photosnapImg = document.querySelector('.photosnap');

// Mouse in add background color title and links
photosnapBackground.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    photosnapBackground.classList.add('active');
    photosnapImg.classList.add('active');
    projectTitle.textContent = 'Photosnap';

    projectTitle.classList.add('active');
    projectLine.classList.add('active');
    projectRowWrap.classList.add('active');
});

// Mouse out remove all
photosnapBackground.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    photosnapBackground.classList.remove('active');
    photosnapImg.classList.remove('active');

    dineBackground.classList.remove('active');
    dineImg.classList.remove('active');

    projectTitle.textContent = '';
    projectTitle.classList.remove('active');
    projectLine.classList.remove('active');
    projectRowWrap.classList.remove('active');
});

//Dine Project #2 ---------------------------------------------------------------

// Content in project on hover 
let projectTitleDine = document.querySelector('.projectTitleDine');
let projectLineDine = document.querySelector('.hoverLineDine');
// View live View code text wrapper
let projectRowWrapDine = document.querySelector('.flexWrapperRowDine');

// Background color + image
let dineBackground = document.querySelector('.dineBackground');
let dineImg = document.querySelector('.dine');

// Mouse in add background color title and links
dineBackground.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    dineBackground.classList.add('active');
    dineImg.classList.add('active');
    projectTitleDine.textContent = 'Dine';

    projectTitleDine.classList.add('active');
    projectLineDine.classList.add('active');
    projectRowWrapDine.classList.add('active');
});

// Mouse out remove all
dineBackground.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    dineBackground.classList.remove('active');
    dineImg.classList.remove('active');

    projectTitleDine.textContent = '';
    projectTitleDine.classList.remove('active');
    projectLineDine.classList.remove('active');
    projectRowWrapDine.classList.remove('active');
});

//Nike Project #3 ---------------------------------------------------------------

// Content in project on hover 
let projectTitleNike = document.querySelector('.projectTitleNike');
let projectLineNike = document.querySelector('.hoverLineNike');
// View live View Code wrapper
let projectRowWrapNike = document.querySelector('.flexWrapperRowNike'); 

// Background color + image
let nikeBackground = document.querySelector('.nikeBackground');
let nikeImg = document.querySelector('.nike');

// Mouse in add background color title and links
nikeBackground.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    nikeBackground.classList.add('active');
    nikeImg.classList.add('active');
    projectTitleNike.textContent = 'Nike';

    projectTitleNike.classList.add('active');
    projectLineNike.classList.add('active');
    projectRowWrapNike.classList.add('active');
});

// Mouse out remove all
nikeBackground.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    nikeBackground.classList.remove('active');
    nikeImg.classList.remove('active');

    projectTitleNike.textContent = '';
    projectTitleNike.classList.remove('active');
    projectLineNike.classList.remove('active');
    projectRowWrapNike.classList.remove('active');
```

HTML--

```
<!-- Projects desktop -->
<div id="horizontalScroll" class="horizontalScroll projectsContainer">
    <!-- Photosnap -->
    <div class="projectsWrapper photosnapBackground">
        <span class="testFunc hoverTitleFont projectTitlePhotosnap"></span>
        <div class="testFunc hoverLine hoverLinePhotosnap"></div>
        <img src="assets/projects/photosnap-desktop-p.jpg" alt="photosnap project" class="photosnap">
        <div class="testFunc flexWrapperRow flexWrapperRowPhotosnap">
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Live</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Code</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Dine -->
    <div class="projectsWrapper dineBackground">
        <span class="testFunc hoverTitleFont projectTitleDine"></span>
        <div class="testFunc hoverLine hoverLineDine"></div>
        <img src="assets/projects/dine-desktop-p.png" alt="dine project" class="dine">
        <div class="testFunc flexWrapperRow flexWrapperRowDine">
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Live</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Code</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Nike -->
    <div class="projectsWrapper nikeBackground">
        <span class="hoverTitleFont projectTitleNike"></span>
        <div class="hoverLine hoverLineNike"></div>
        <img src="assets/projects/nike-desktop-p.png" alt="nike project" class="nike">
        <div class="flexWrapperRow flexWrapperRowNike">
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Live</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Code</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, one question to ask yourself is if you need to do this with JavaScript at all; Most of this could be likely be done with CSS alone (depending on the HTML structure, which if you were to provide, might go a long way toward answering).

Comment: I figured i could do this with just CSS but i decided to go ahead and use javascript because i wanted to get some practice with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're using 3 times the same function, so we sure can do better.
Here is a first simple idea, make a loop on the tree elements :

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
          let slide = ['Photosnap', 'Dine', 'Nike'] ;
        for (let i = 0; i < slide.length ; i++ ) {
            let lowercaseName =  slide[i].toLowerCase() ;
            let projectTitle = document.querySelector('.projectTitle' + slide[i]);
            let projectLine = document.querySelector('.hoverLine' + slide[i]);
    // View live View code text wrapper
            let projectRowWrap = document.querySelector('.flexWrapperRow'+ slide[i]);
    // Background color + image
            let background = document.querySelector('.'+ lowercaseName+'Background');
            let img = document.querySelector('.'+ lowercaseName);
    // Mouse in add background color title and links
            background.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
                background.classList.add('active');
                img.classList.add('active');
                projectTitle.textContent = slide[i];
                projectTitle.classList.add('active');
                projectLine.classList.add('active');
                projectRowWrap.classList.add('active');
            });
    // Mouse out remove all
            background.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
                background.classList.remove('active');
                img.classList.remove('active');
                background.classList.remove('active');
                img.classList.remove('active');
                projectTitle.textContent = '';
                projectTitle.classList.remove('active');
                projectLine.classList.remove('active');
                projectRowWrap.classList.remove('active');
            });
        }
```

Another approche, or to upgrate this solution can be use "data" attribute, like "data-id" or "data-color" you can give the name you want and have as many "data" atributes you want on DOM element.
You could save classname too, catching element's child of the main block with .childNodes.

Comment: wow that works great thank you! Ive never seen classes selected that way i.e let background = document.querySelector('.' + lowercaseName + 'Background'); so thats great to know you can do it that way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some updation in html structure before we move to javascript.

We want to keep HTML as much strucutural as we want. So that similar elements can be easily selected.

1. Make it easier to group project related element.
2. Remove unnecessary class name.

Added comments where every necessary.

```html
<!-- Projects desktop -->
<div id="horizontalScroll" class="horizontalScroll projectsContainer">
    <!-- Photosnap -->
    <div class="projectsWrapper photosnap Background"> <!-- Remove backgound here, if you its needed for class selection in css seperate it -->
        <span class="testFunc hoverTitleFont projectTitle"></span> <!-- Remove photosnap-->
        <div class="testFunc hoverLine"></div> <!-- Remove hoverLinePhotosnap-->
        <img src="assets/projects/photosnap-desktop-p.jpg" alt="photosnap project" class="photosnapImg"> <!-- Since there is only 1 img tag inside photosnap we can select through img tag-->
        <div class="testFunc flexWrapperRow"> <!-- remove flexWrapperRowPhotosnap-->
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Live</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Code</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Dine -->
    <div class="projectsWrapper dine Background"> <!-- seperated background-->
        <span class="testFunc hoverTitleFont projectTitle"></span> <!--remove Dine-->
        <div class="testFunc hoverLine"></div> <!--remove hoverLineDine-->
        <img src="assets/projects/dine-desktop-p.png" alt="dine project" class="dineImg">
        <div class="testFunc flexWrapperRow"> <!--removed flexWrapperRowDine-->
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Live</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Code</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Nike -->
    <div class="projectsWrapper nike Background"> <!--seperated backgound-->
        <span class="hoverTitleFont projectTitle"></span> <!--removed nike-->
        <div class="hoverLine"></div> <!--removed hoverLineNike-->
        <img src="assets/projects/nike-desktop-p.png" alt="nike project" class="nikeImg">
        <div class="flexWrapperRow"> <!--removed flexWrapperRowNike-->
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Live</span>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">
                <span class="hoverIconFont">View Code</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now we have our proper html structure we can move to js

1. A function to add class and other property to the element
2. A function to remove class from the element

```js
// property being an object {textContent: "photosnap", backgroundColor: "red"}
function addProperty(element, property) {
    // I belive there are 4 Elements that need to be selected
    const title = element.querySelector("projectTitle");
    const projectLine = element.querySelector("hoverLine");
    const projectRowWrap = element.querySelector("flexWrapperRow");
    const image = element.querySelector("img");

    // if removing looks like code duplicate elements can be pushed to an array, and iterate over it to add/remove the class
    /*
        const elementList = [];
        elementList.push(element);
        elementList.push(image);
        elementList.push(title);
        elementList.push(projectLine);
        elementList.push(projectRowWrap);
        elementList.forEach(el => {
            el.classList.add("active");
        });
      */
    title.textContent = property.textContent;

    element.classList.add("active");
    image.classList.add("active");
    title.classList.add("active");
    projectLine.classList.add("active");
    projectRowWrap.classList.add("active");


}

function removeProperty(element) {
    const title = element.querySelector("projectTitle");
    const projectLine = element.querySelector("hoverLine");
    const projectRowWrap = element.querySelector("flexWrapperRow");
    const image = element.querySelector("img");
    title.textContent = "";
    element.classList.remove("active");
    image.classList.remove("active");
    title.classList.remove("active");
    projectLine.classList.remove("active");
    projectRowWrap.classList.remove("active");
}

const element = document.querySelector("photosnap");

element.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
    const eventElement = event.target;
    const property = { textContent: "photosnap" };
    addProperty(eventElement, property);
});

element.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
    removeProperty(event.target);
});
```